# Convert the Normal class to generic in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, class-transformer

I have a class to get JSON objects and convert them to the class that I want. the code is below.

```js
import {plainToClass} from "class-transformer";
import UserDto from "../../auth/dto/user.dto";

class ConvertJson {
    
    userData(data) {
        return plainToClass(UserDto, data);
    }
}
```

when I want to convert the class to generaic class

```js
import {plainToClass} from "class-transformer";
import UserDto from "../../auth/dto/user.dto";

class ConvertJson<T> {

    userData(data) {
        return plainToClass(T, data);
    }
}
```

I get this error

> T only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Comment: `T` is a type, not value. You need to accept constructor argument like `userData<T>(ctor: { new(): T; }, ...) {...}`, `userData(UserDto, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tweaking the code I found out that typescript generic is very different from C# or other languages so I convert the code to this so it has a generic vibe but not syntax.

```js
import {plainToClass} from "class-transformer";

interface IClass {
    new (...args : any[])
}

class ConvertJson {

    constructor(private dto : IClass) {
    }

    userData(data) {
        return plainToClass(this.dto, data);
    }
}
```

> the reason I use IClass instead of any is that I want to make sure
> other teammates use class, not other types.

Answer (score 1):

Enhance from Milad's comment
`class-transformer` provide some generic class to do the same as he introduced.

```js
import { plainToClass, ClassConstructor } from "class-transformer";

class ConvertJson {
    userData<TargetClass>(data: unknown, dtoClass: ClassConstructor<TargetClass>) {
        return plainToClass(dtoClass, data);
    }
}
```

My `class-transformer` version is v0.5.1

> ✍Note:
> `plainToClasss` is deprecated❌
> Use `plainToInstance` instead (it's same)✅

Answer (score -3):

I guess want you want to do is cast the output according to the input type

```
class ConvertJson<T> {
    userData(data) {
        return <T>plainToClass(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: this just removes the error but doesn't work, I get this error when in runtime " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')"

Comment: @Milad of course you will get an error, since your plainToClass method expects two arguments. I gave you a hint on how to Cast... Do not expect the full solution when you do not provide the method's code